# Effect of AV_CODEC_FLAG2_FAST in decoding H.264

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

Does anyone know what is the effect of `AV_CODEC_FLAG2_FAST` flag in libavcodec library (ffmpeg 4.0.2) when is set on `AVCodecContext`?

```
AVCodecContext* avCodecContext;
AVCodec* avCodec;

...
avCodec = ...;
avCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(avCodec);
avCodecContext->flags2 |= AV_CODEC_FLAG2_FAST;
...
// start receiving stream and parsing and decoding frames
...
```

As I have tested on an AXIS camera, I cannot see any difference in decoding performance when this flag is set, compared to not using this flag.

Any idea, any information appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a quick glance at the code, in multi-threaded decoding, the h264 decodes normally macroblocks in parallel, skipping the in-loop filter. Once the whole frame has been decoded, deblocking filter is applied serially, which can occur across slice boundaries.

With the flag set, the deblocking is no longer postponed. The tradeoff is that deblocking does not cross slice boundaries, so there may be discontinuities/artifacts at slice edges.

I would guess any relative speed-up would be prominent when decoding uses many threads.

Comment: Does it have any effects on CPU usage (or GPU usage when using GPU decoders)? For example, can we expect to reach lower CPU usage for the same h.264 data, when this flag is set?

Comment: Only affects s/w decoder. Has little effect on CPU % since this flag affects *when* the filtering happens.

Answer (score 1):

If disable_deblocking_filter_idc = 2 (i.e. deblocking across slice boundaries is disabled and consequently each slice is completely self-contained) in input stream then the flag AV_CODEC_FLAG2_FAST has not effect.

Otherwise visual impairments can be observed (due to a drift between encoding and decoding processes), especially if number of slices per pframe is high and/or the interval between successive IDR frames is long (due to temporal propagation).

Notice that IDR frames don't eliminate the drift, they merely reduce it.